# Converting VB.NET ADODB to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Hi I have been trying to convert an app I have to c# and I have also used some tools out there to give me a base to work with. I am using ADODB and as a result what has been working in VB.NET i cannot get to work in C#.

The error i get is nearly the same error for calling two particular methods in the ADODB.Command object.

I have the following declaration

```
private Connection objConnection = new Connection();
private Command objCommand = new Command();
```

then i use the ADODB command object objCommand to either open the connection or execute the query/procedure.

```
if (objCommand.ActiveConnection.State != (int) ConnectionState.Open)
{
   objCommand.ActiveConnection.Open();
}

objCommand.Execute();
```

and

```
rs = objCommand.Execute();
```

neither of these seem to work and I get the following errors

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'Open' takes '0' arguments
```

and

```
Error   2   No overload for method 'Execute' takes '0' arguments
```

can any body help me as I am new to C# and I am wondering if I have missed a glaring obvious fact that VB.NET hides.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [documentation for connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676505(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll see it has 4 parameters, all of which are optional. However in c# optional isn't supported. So you'll have to figure out what to pass in place of each of those parameters to instruct it to do its default behaviour. I'm suspecting using null in a lot of places will handle it.

Comment: What do you mean "optional isn't supported" - C# has had optional parameter support for years now.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - sorry, optional wasn't supported. Hence why all parameters despite being marked as optional are mandatory when called through c#.